# How to call method in ViewController from viewmodel in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I am using MVVM design pattern in iOS project. I am trying to call method in viewcontroller from viewmodel.

```
import Foundation

class NotificationViewModel {

    var onCompletion: ((_ success: Bool) -> ())?

    func saveNotification(notification: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        print("notification save")
        //other logic
        onCompletion?(true)
    }
   }
```

"saveNotification" method getting called from appdelegate when notification received

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        guard
            let aps = userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary,
            let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSMutableDictionary
            else {
                // handle any error here
                return
            }   

        NotificationViewModel().saveNotification(notification: alert as! Dictionary<String, Any>)
        }
```

trying to call method in viewcontroller when "saveNotification" trigger

```
     class AlertViewController: BaseViewController{


            var viewModel = NotificationViewModel()

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                self.viewModel.onCompletion = { success in
                    // this should be executed when `saveNotification()` will be called
// **** this is never getting called ******
                    print("calling from viewmodel")
                    methodToCall()
                }
            }

          func methodToCall(){
            //logic
          }
      }
```

But the method in viewdidload is not getting called anytime.

Please suggest if its possible or any other way to achieve this?
Thanks for help

Comment: From your code, it would be `func someButtonTapped () { ... viewModel.saveNotificationnotification: ...) }`.

Comment: @Larme sorry its just typo..corrected

Comment: Wouldn't this break MVVM?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson in that method in viewcontroller i want to reload tableview.. I am not sure how can i achieve this through viewmodel

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? You didn't mention that. Is the "calling from viewmodel" not getting printed ?

Comment: @VincentJoy the method in viewdidload is not getting called anytime..question updated

Comment: you said "saveNotification" method getting called from appdelegate when notification received.. how is that? can you add that code also ?

Answer (score 2):

MVVM without Rx framework(RxSwift,ReactiveCocoa or Apple Combine) is a pain.
Below is my Solution in MVVM + RxSwift.Hopefully that will inspire you.

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

final class NotificationViewModel: ViewModel, ViewModelType {

    struct Input { }

    struct Output {
        let compelete: PublishSubject<Bool>
    }

    let input: Input = Input()

    let output: Output = Output(compelete: PublishSubject<Bool>())
}

import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import Rswift

final class NotificationViewController: ViewController<LoginViewModel> {

    override func bindViewModel() {

        vm.output.compelete
            .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] _ in
                // this will be executed when `saveNotification()` will be called
                print("calling from viewmodel")
                methodToCall()
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    }

    private func methodToCall(){
        //logic
    }

}
```

Whenever you would like to ask view controller to invoke methodToCall function.Simply call `output.complete.onNext(true)` in your view model.

Comment: Thanks for great solution

Comment: you are welcome,MVVM without Rx is like soup without salt.Now,we can choose Apple Combine as native reactive functional framework.Good Luck to your journey to Rx master.

Comment: Thank you dear. I resolved my issue with your help! I was unable to find viewModel output function.

Answer (score 1):

No need `NotificationViewModel`

you just need to show alert in app delegate dirrectly

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    guard let aps = userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary,
        let alertDict = aps["alert"] as? NSMutableDictionary else {
            // handle any error here
            return
        }   

    let alert = AlertViewController()

    alert.showAlert(dict: alertDict)
}
```

Your Alert class :

```
class AlertViewController: BaseViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func showAlert(dict: Dictionary<String, Any>){
        // do show alert
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the **NotificationViewModel()** in Appdelegate and **viewModel** variable in AlertViewController, they are not same, both are 2 different instances of the NotificationViewModel class. You need to go back to the basics and understand the concepts of class, struct, instances etc. Explaining that fully is beyond the scope of this answer. You can start [from here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html) for instance.

For now I would suggest, since you have yet to grasp these concepts, you better stick with MVC and use NotificationCenter to pass message from AppDelegate to AlertViewController directly. Here are some useful tutorials about NotificationCenter :-

1. https://learnappmaking.com/notification-center-how-to-swift/
2. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-post-messages-using-notificationcenter

PS. Appreciate that you are trying MVVM architecture from the starting itself, but make sure you keep the foundation/basics also strong along the journey, preferably from the starting itself. All the best :)

Comment: Thanks i will definitely take a look